# How can you tell a service worker what assets it should cache vs which ones it should not?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, offline-caching

I am trying to find a clean strategy to have a service worker differentiate assets that should be cached vs. assets that should never be cashed.

#### Example

1. App fetches an image file that corresponds to the user's avatar which rarely changes.
2. App fetches a virtually endless list of image files as dynamic, ever-changing content (think Pinterest's infinite scroll).

#### Problem

The service worker only sees *generic* image file requests that are basically impossible to tell apart, with only the app having enough context to differentiate the two.

Is there a clean strategy to tell the service worker what to cache and what not to cache?

Comment: What do you mean with "The service worker only sees generic image file requests"? I sees nothing, your code is running in a service worker, make your code know what it's fetching?

Comment: What I mean is that since service workers are fully decoupled from the app context they don't have enough information to be able to differentiate both types of requests (avatar image vs normal image). I'm just trying to figure out a clean strategy to be able to "hint" the service worker which requests should be subject to caching and which ones should. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: why would your service worker be pulling images at all? That main app functionality. Service workers are for "doing work off-thread, the result of which can be yielded to the caller once done". What are you actually doing?

Comment: Well, handling fetch requests on behalf of the application is exactly the purpose of service workers. When a SW intercepts a fetch request for any asset (images, videos, or whatever, the asset type is inconsequential) you get a chance of fully controlling how to respond to it (hence the various strategies, e.g. cache-first, network-first, stale-while-revalidate, etc etc). The issue is that (as far as I can tell) there's nothing the SW can see in the request itself to be able to tell whether the request should be cached or not, it ends up being an application concern the SW knows nothing about.